# Sorting latest time and date using leaf #loop and custom tag using MySql. Vapor, Fluent

Tags: html, swift, fluent, vapor, leaf

I have an issue with sorting date new first using Tag in leaf, vapor. From MySQL database, its showing the date and time but new entry at the end when I use "get" in routes.swift and perfectly show date and time in HTML on the webpage. My each entity date and time is successfully fetched from MySQL but new user entity comes at the end after using #loop in leaf. Is there any way possible to #loop in latest time and date first. Below is code.

Custom Tag code

```
import Leaf
import Fluent

final public class LeafDataPoint: BasicTag {

public var name = "dataPoint"

public func run(arguments: ArgumentList) throws -> Node? {
    guard
        arguments.count == 3,
        let report = arguments[0],
        let dataPointName = arguments[1]?.string,
        let dateField = arguments[2]?.string
    else {
        return nil
    }
    let point = try DataPointFluent.makeQuery()
        .filter(DataPointFluent.Keys.reportID, 
 report.get(ReportFluent.Keys.id) as String)
        .filter(DataPointFluent.Keys.name, dataPointName.string)
        .first()


    switch dateField {
    case DataPointFluent.Keys.data:
        return point?.data?.makeNode(in: nil)
    case DataPointFluent.Keys.displayName:
        return point?.displayName.makeNode(in: nil)

    default:
        return nil
    }

}
}
```

In Routes.swift

```
  get("machine", String.parameter) {req in
        let machineSerial = try req.parameters.next(String.self)
        let reports = try ReportFluent.byMachine(serial: machineSerial)
        return try self.view.make("machine_overview.leaf",["reports": 
reports,"id": machineSerial])
    }
```

machine_overview.leaf

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th><h3>Date</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Location</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Link</h3></th>
        </tr>
        #loop(reports, "report") {

        <tr>
            <td>#(report.date)</td>
            <td>#dataPoint(report, "ort", "data")</td>

            <td><a href="/bericht/#(report.id)">Complete Report Data</a></td>

        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

I have tried with loop.isFirst but did not succeed.

Comment: using #offset on loop shows the number of data in array index, can its possible to reverse the array.

Comment: Can you post the `ReportFluent.byMachine` method? I think that method is the one that needs to be changed.